# Routing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I am confused with codeigniter routing. I am implementing URL masking in my project by using router in codeigniter.

From this I got confusion about the routing.routes has given below.

```
$route['project/shareToFacebook/(:any)']="project/shareToFacebook/$1";
$route['project/shareToFacebook/(:any)']="project/profile/$1";
```

My question is when I called the controller `shareToFacebook` what does route will do?

whether controller `profile` will be invoke or the controller `shareToFacebook` will be invoke?

Comment: The first one, they are read in the order they appear (and then the routing stop)

Comment: ok,the answer is exactly I want. I got the confusion because of usually second line override first line.But here found as instant when routing matches then it will invoke routed controller and stop further checking for routes.Thank you for the support.

Comment: -1 simply you can try it, or look at the codeigniter doucmentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

[CodeIgniter user guide: Routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

You will always be sent to `shareToFacebook`, but you will be sent to any of these routes only if you pass some parameters so when you will call the controller it will open it's index method regardless, if you won't pass any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

**when I called the controller shareToFacebook what does route will do?**

The method 'shareToFacebook' will accept 1 parameter ex.

if you call ex. localhost/yourproject/profile/shareToFacebook/1 <- will be passed on the method shareToFacebook
    `public function shareToFacebbok($value)`

and you can do what ever you want with that value.

**whether controller profile will be invoke or the controller shareToFacebook will be invoke?**

No.

profile will still call its index method

Comment: Wrong, profile will not be loaded under any circumstances, see my answer